# Remove automatic page break after paragraph

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, report

i'm using the report class and have set the section depth to 5 using the following command:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

However, when I use the \paragraph{} section, the compiled pdf adds a page break before the next section.

[image]

How can I get rid of this page break?

Example:

```
\paragraph{example section}~\\ \indent
example phrase
```

**edit 02/29/16**
It was brought up that the code posted does not produce the same result. So here's the code:

```
\documentclass{report}

% Set paper size
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

% This sets up the header.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Indent first paragraph of each section
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% Adding pictures
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Provides unnumbered equations
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Number citations based on position in text and not TOC, LOF, LOT, LOE
\usepackage{notoccite}

% Common text symbols
\usepackage{textcomp}

% url and section linking support
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black]            {hyperref}

% Section levels
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} % depth of sections/paragraphs
% \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}  % depth of table of contents

% Acronym package
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{first-style=short}

% include pdfs
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Properly format code
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                {-3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
...
\subsubsection{CRS Safety}
\subsection{Previous Team's Project}
\section{Biometrics}
\subsection{Detecting the User State}
\subsubsection{Electrical Activity in Skeletal Muscles}
\paragraph{Muscle Control of Lower Limb Movement in Transfemoral Amputee}
that when i type for a paragraph

...
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

I don't mind that the text starts on the same line as much as that there's now a page break after the paragraph.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try to add a `\nobreak` after the paragraph

Comment: `~\\ \indent` completely breaks latex's control over spacing and line and page breaking around a section head. remove that and page breaking will be restored. If you want paragraph to be a display head not inline, specify that elsewhere, as it is for \section.

Comment: @User No that would not help.

Answer (score 4):

The posted code does not produce the image shown (`example phrase` comes on the next line) Nor does it allow a page break, the code below shows

[image]

If you reduce the page height by one line, by changing

```
\addtolength\textheight{-9\baselineskip}
```

to

```
\addtolength\textheight{-10\baselineskip}
```

The whole of the `\paragraph` section, including its heading moves to the next page.

```
\documentclass{report}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\addtolength\textheight{-9\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\chapter{zzz}
Z

ZZ

ZZ

\section{aaa}
A

AA
\subsection{bbb}
B

BB
\subsubsection{qqqqqqq}
Q

QQ

\paragraph{example section}~\\ \indent
example phrase

EEE1

EEE2
\end{document}
```

However you should never use a construct such as `~\\ \indent` You should just use `\paragraph` as you would use `\section`. If you need to make it into a display heading, adjust its definition using `\@startsection`

```
\documentclass{report}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\addtolength\textheight{-9\baselineskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{zzz}
Z

ZZ

ZZ

\section{aaa}
A

AA
\subsection{bbb}
B

BB
\subsubsection{qqqqqqq}
Q

QQ

\paragraph{example section}
example phrase

EEE1

EEE2
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see my update for a better example of the code and what is going on. I added the \renewcommand phrase you listed to my preamble and got the following error:

You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.180 \paragraph
                {Muscle Control of Lower Limb Movement in Transfemoral Amputee}

Comment: @jlzizmor there is no usable code in your question _at all_ !! The example should be like the example in this question a complete self contained document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that reproduces the error. the spacefactor error just means that you forgot to use `\makeatletter`.

Comment: I added the \makeatletter command as suggested, that added the newline & indent, but it still has a page break after each \paragraph. I added more complete code to my question

Comment: @jlzizmor you are asking a question about _a bad page break_ and your new example is a 1 page file. So whatever it is an example of, it is not an example of the problem described.

Comment: i wasn't sure how to show it, but the issue is that after all of my \paragraph{} headers, the rest of the page is empty and the next page is blank. the rest of the doc continues after the full blank page

Comment: @jlzizmor  just write any text, or use the `lipsum` package and the command `\lipsum` to generate nonsense text to fill out the page and show the problem. it is quite likely that the problem is unrelated to the `paragraph` command but rather by the material on the next page _about which you have given no clue_.